# nginx+php-fpm runs slowly(It's very slow to open the page) in WSL

Tags: php, nginx

I have this very strange problem.

I install nginx and php-fpm in WSL

Then I wrote it index.php The content is `<? PHP echo 'hello world';`

Then open it through a browser

It often runs more than 100s (php-fpm.ini `request_terminate_timeout` default value) before it has output

But if I run `service php-fpm reload` in the WSL

The page loads immediately

Occasionally, however, pages can load normally and return content immediately.

If i change `request_terminate_timeout`value to 4 in php-fpm.ini

The page will load in 4 seconds

If I try to access a static file, I always return quickly.

I try to run `php index.php` in shell

It always returns content quickly

Besides, I found the problem

https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1484

I tried to move my code from /mnt to another dir

But it still hasn't solved the problem

I can't find the cause of the problem

Can someone give me some advice?

php-fpm.ini

```
[global]
pid = /www/server/php/72/var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /www/server/php/72/var/log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice

[www]
listen = /tmp/php-cgi-72.sock
listen.backlog = 8192
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0666
user = www
group = www
pm = static
pm.status_path = /phpfpm_72_status
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 30
request_terminate_timeout = 4
request_slowlog_timeout = 0
slowlog = var/log/slow.log
```

php.ini

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = -1
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 50M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 50M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
date.timezone = PRC
[filter]
[iconv]
[imap]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mail.add_x_header = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
[openssl]
openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
[Zend ZendGuard Loader]
extension = /www/server/php/72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/fileinfo.so
[ImageMagick]
extension = "imagick.so"
[redis]
extension = /www/server/php/72/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/redis.so
```